# Removing Hyper-V role from Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I am attempting to remove they Hyper-V role from a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. When attempting to do so via the "Add Roles and Features Wizard", the check box is grayed out and it will not allow me to uncheck it and therefore will not allow me to uninstall this role.

This was a simple process in 2008 and 2008 R2. Not sure what has changed.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the `Remove Roles and Features` wizard? How about posting a screenshot of that window?

Answer (score 21):

Windows Server 2012 R2 is all about PowerShell and frankly with the redesign of Server Manager I'm quite glad.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V
```

Answer (score 14):

First start  "Add Roles and Features Wizard" and then switch to the "Remove Roles and Features Wizard". And there it is possible to remove Hyper-V role.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hyper-V is checked and disabled. I can't uncheck this. Any solution..? Also, it is mentioned as `Hyper-V (Installed)`.

Comment: Had the same problem, the Powershell solution here worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and @kce's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/598229/205065) of removing Hyper-V using PowerShell cured the problem for me to.

As a few further points, you need to run PowerShell as an Administrator. To do that in the search box on the Start Menu type `powershell`. It will turn up various variants of PowerShell. I used **Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell**. It should open with the prompt `PS C:\Windows\system32>`.

After that type the command given in @kce's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/598229/205065):

```
remove-windowsfeature -name Hyper-V
```

It will take a minute or two to remove the feature. After that you need to restart the machine to complete the removal of Hyper-V.